# download data from CoinMarketCap API

Tags: r, api, coinbase-api

I want to download coinmarketcap of cryptocoins data. When compiling the code below:

```
rm(list = ls())
cat("\014")
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)
base_url <- "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/"
path <- "v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?start=1&limit=5000&convert=USD&CMC_PRO_API_KEY="
endpoint <- paste(base_url, path, sep="/")
key_api <- Sys.getenv("MyKey")
res_api <- GET(
  url = endpoint, 
  query = list(
    apikey= key_api,
    details = "true"
  )
)
res_api
```

I get the following answer:

```
Response [https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?start=1&limit=5000&convert=USD&CMC_PRO_API_KEY=&apikey=&details=true]
  Date: 2021-09-02 17:14
  Status: 401
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 195 B
{
    "status": {
        "timestamp": "2021-09-02T17:14:20....
        "error_code": 1002,
        "error_message": "API key missing.",
        "elapsed": 0,
        "credit_count": 0
    }
```

A 401 status means that my request does not have valid authentication credentials and that I probably have some problem with my API key. However, my key is correct. can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm Normally using python to interact with the API,
But reading your post I found something

This is part of your response

```
https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?start=1&limit=5000&convert=USD&CMC_PRO_API_KEY=&apikey=&details=true
```

Check the query parameters

`&CMC_PRO_API_KEY=&apikey=&details=true`

Both `CMC_PRO_API_KEY` and `apikey` are empty.

You need to pass the API key either as part of the string query or as part of the headers, it seems you are trying to do both.

I think a request using headers will be a good option, and it must be something like this:

```
GET('https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?start=1&limit=5000&convert=USD', 
      accept_json(), 
      add_headers('CMC_PRO_API_KEY' = 'YOUR_API_KEY'))
```